# Remove component with in next update in WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, serviceinstall

I have a service component installed twice in one of my previous releases.

```
<Component Id="MyServiceWin7" Guid="{GUID_WIN7}">
<File Id="mysvc_Win7"
      Name="mysvc.exe"
      Source=mysvc.exe"
      KeyPath = "yes"/>
<ServiceControl Id="MYSVC_Win7"
                Name="MYSVC"
                Remove="uninstall"
                Start="install"
                Stop="both"
                Wait="no" />
<ServiceInstall Id="My_Svc_Win7"
                Name="MYSVC"
                DisplayName="MYSVC"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Start="auto"
                ErrorControl="normal"
                LoadOrderGroup=""
                Description="My service">
</component>

<Component Id="MyServiceWin8" Guid="{GUID_WIN8}">
<File Id="mysvc_Win8"
      Name="mysvc.exe"
      Source=mysvc.exe"
      KeyPath = "yes"/>
<ServiceControl Id="MYSVC_Win8"
                Name="MYSVC"
                Remove="uninstall"
                Start="install"
                Stop="both"
                Wait="no" />
<ServiceInstall Id="My_Svc_Win8"
                Name="MYSVC"
                DisplayName="MYSVC"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Start="auto"
                ErrorControl="normal"
                LoadOrderGroup=""
                Description="My service">
</component>
```

So there will be two instances of the MYSVC component. Both are mapping to MYSVC.exe.

I missed the OS version condition check in the previous release.

It runs successfully.

I am thinking to delete the dummy additional COMPONENT (GUID_Win7 or GUID_WIN8) in the next update.

How I can delete it, do I need to write a custom action?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT::**
Please find answers,

1. mysvc is having some third party lib dependancy os specific Win7 and Win8, it works means it installed successfully if we check sc qc mysvc I get service created and mysvc.exe is mapped to service binpath
2. yes these two service components targets same destinationand there is only one component when I do sc query  mysvc
3. No there only one entry of service. mysvc.exe is win8 version on disk.

Thanks for suggestions, that breaking link.

Currently I have %ProgramFiles%\MyApp\mysvc.exe common path for both win 7 and win8.
So my question if create new common path to break previous link.
ProgramFiles%\MyApp\mysvc\mysvc.exe [[NEW_GUID1]] for win7
ProgramFiles%\MyApp\mysvc\mysvc.exe [[NEW_GUID2]] for win8

Components with [[OLD_GUID1]] , [[OLD_GUID2]] will be on system forever 
until my product is uninstalled, so cant we just delete components with [[OLD_GUID1]], [[OLD_GUID2]] to clean stale(non functional) components

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? What did you try so far to solve the problem on your own?

Comment: Thanks @zett42, I have edited my question. I will add condtion check based on OS version. but there will one service COMPONENT as dummy forever. So thinking to remove the entry.

Comment: Please see my questions below. We need some clarifications.

Comment: The third party lib, is it installed via a separate component or a separate setup? Are the actual binaries used for your services different at all, or are they identical and only the third party files differ?

Comment: No, these files are 2 OS specific libs and linked in mysvc.exe(win7), mysvc.exe(win8)

Comment: So it is two flavours of the same file with the same name then? Where are these library files installed? Next to your service files?

Comment: These lib files are not part of installation. These are linked as in mysvc.exe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176313/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-user3664223).

Answer (score 1):

***Some Questions***:

- First of all, can we ask why you decided to install the service in two flavors? Does this mean that the service has different binaries for Win7 and Win8? If so, then it is unclear why you say it works as it stands.
- Do these service components target two different installation locations so they both run **side-by-side**, or do you **target the same target destination** with both components? (so there is only one instance of the file after installation).
- Are there two entries in the list of services on the box after installation? If you target the same location with both components, what file version of `mysvc.exe` made it onto the disk? (if they are different).

I wrote the below before the above questions. Please update your question with the answers to the questions. The below might be irrellevant - we need more information.

---

***Sins of The Past***: If you have installed the same file twice with two different component GUIDs in the previous version then this is wrong and I would recommend you **"break the link**" to the sins of the past by setting **two new component GUIDs** for the new release and crucially: **set a new absolute installation location for each component** (do not target the same absolute key path with two different GUIDs! - conditions or not).

The idea is to de-couple the old and new versions so that you start with a clean(er) slate.

Something like:

`Comp 1: {77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777}, [ProgramFilesFolder]My App\Win7\mysvc.exe`

`Comp 2: {42424242-4242-4242-4242-424242424242}, [ProgramFilesFolder]My App\Win8\mysvc.exe`

Personally I would avoid the Windows version number and maybe use something else. How about a year?

`Comp 1: {77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777}, [ProgramFilesFolder]My App\2007\mysvc.exe`

`Comp 2: {42424242-4242-4242-4242-424242424242}, [ProgramFilesFolder]My App\2014\mysvc.exe`

Just to not hard code a misleading value if the Win8 version runs on Win10 for example.

> **N.B!**: Note that [the above, sample GUIDs are well-known and dysfunctional GUIDs](https://twitter.com/glytzhkof/status/1017754199948517377) and
>   should not be copied and used! This is of high cruciality :-).